# AWS Amplify - How to handle name of resources in different environments

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I used Amplify CLI to add storage and functions. When I deploy these changes, the names have a suffix of the environment name. For example, the dynamo tables are named "table1-dev", "table2-dev" and lambda functions are named "function1-dev" and "function2-dev". This is making code hard to maintain.

Is there a way to fix this or handle this scenario. This is a typical 3-tier architecture, so I need API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB components.

Comment: I would like a better solution as well... If I am using boto3 within a Lambda function to access data from a dynamo table, I don't know what the name will be from dev to test to prod (in our setup, Amplify inserts a long random string between the table name and the environment, e.g. mytable-sidufbfhbfihlwefv-dev). Definitely frustrating.